# MongoDB update many with switch fails - The dollar ($) prefixed field '$switch' in 'offerCategoryState.$switch' is not valid for storage

Tags: mongodb

I have the following table:

[image]

I have to set `offerCategoryState` column with following rule:

- ***DEPOSIT*** or ***INSURANCE*** -> ***ENABLED***
- ***DIGITAL_CARD*** -> ***SOON***
- others -> ***BLOCKED***

I wrote query for doing this with `updateMany()`:

```
db.OFFER_CATEGORIES.updateMany(
    {},
    { $set: { offerCategoryState: { $switch: {
               branches: [
                   { case: { $eq: [ "$type", 'DEPOSIT' ] }, then: "ENABLED" },
                   { case: { $eq: [ "$type", 'INSURANCE' ] }, then: "ENABLED" },
                   { case: { $eq: [ "$type", 'DIGITAL_CARD' ] }, then: "SOON" },
               ],
               default: "BLOCKED"
    } } } }
);
```

Unfortunatelly, it fails:

> Write error: WriteError{code=52, message='The dollar ($) prefixed field '$switch' in 'offerCategoryState.$switch' is not valid for storage.', details={}

***How to write such a mongo DB query where setting one column depends on another?***

Or even more how to add this new columnt if it doesn't exists at current schema (when set up at new environment).

Comment: You can use Updates with Aggregation Pipeline (requires MongoDB v4.2+).

Comment: @prasad_ what do you mean?

Comment: _"How to write such a mongo DB query where setting one column depends on another?"_ You can use Updates with Aggregation Pipeline feature for such an update operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$switch` is used in [`.aggregation`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/#example) only so can't use it in `.updateMany`.

Alternatively you can do this

```
db.OFFER_CATEGORIES.updateMany({}, { $set: { offerCategoryState: 'BLOCKED' } })
db.OFFER_CATEGORIES.updateMany({ type: 'DEPOSIT' }, { $set: { offerCategoryState: 'ENABLED' } })
db.OFFER_CATEGORIES.updateMany({ type: 'INSURANCE' }, { $set: { offerCategoryState: 'ENABLED' } })
db.OFFER_CATEGORIES.updateMany({ type: 'DIGITAL_CARD' }, { $set: { offerCategoryState: 'SOON' } })
```

Comment: simple but it works fine